# How to implement websockets on an embedded device server?

Tags: embedded, push, embedded-linux, websocket, embeddedwebserver

I am working with an electronics appliance manufacturer to embed LAN based control systems into the products. The idea is to serve up a system configuration/control interface through a web browser so clients never need to install software. We can communicate with the appliance by sending and receiving serial data through the embedded module. Since the appliance can also be controlled from a front panel UI, it creates a challenge to keep a remote web interface in sync with very low latency. It seems like websockets or some sort of Push is what we need for handling real time events from the server to clients.

I am using a Lantronix Mathport AR embedded device server. Out of the box the unit will serve up any custom HTML and java servlets/applets. We have the option to install a lightweight Linux distro if we need more flexibility. I am not sure how to implement any server side apps since the device is not running standard Apache. I believe it is using Boa.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Some general info...The WebSocket protocol ([draft spec here](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-60.pdf)) is a simple layer on top of TCP. What this means is that, if you already have a TCP server for your platform, implementing the WebSocket is just a matter of hours. The protocol specifies a handshake and two ways of sending data frames.

I strongly suggest you start by reading the 39 pages spec.

Answer (score 2):

As Tihauan already mentioned, start by reading the spec, and also note that there are still some changes ongoing, although websockets is now more stable than it was 1 year ago.

Key point for me was the requirement that websocket data is entirely UTF-8 text, which lends itself nicely to JSON based message definitions.

Our system uses a form of embedded linux, so we then added and made use of the following libraries:

- "libwebsockets" from:
  http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/
- "jansson" from:
  http://www.digip.org/jansson/

Using the above as support libraries, we created an internal lightweight "client/server" that allowed our other software modules to register for certain, applicable, websocket messages, and respond as needed.   Worked great.

Good luck and best regards,

Comment: Could you please share some example code for the client application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but Mozilla posted a guide entitled "Writing WebSocket servers", which literally guides you through writing a websocket server.

> You will need to already know how HTTP works and have medium programming experience. Depending on language support, knowledge of TCP sockets may be required. The scope of this guide is to present the minimum knowledge you need to write a WebSocket server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers